# Listview has Arrayadpater with edittext

Tags: android-listview, android-edittext, android-arrayadapter

I have single view layout with edit text and image. To display data in listview i am using arrayadapter . While entering value in Edit text in first row. The data gets repeated to another row in listview . How can i resolve this ?

```
View rowView = null;
    try {
        if (convertView == null) {
            //inflating view.
            rowView = 
 inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single_view,null,false); 

        }
        else 
        {
            //Setting view if layout is already implemented.
            rowView = convertView;
        }

        imageView = (ImageView)  
rowView.findViewById(R.id.iv_activity_image_single);

        //Facing issue here in editText . The entered text gets repeated 
        et_image_name = (EditText)    
rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_user_notes);
        et_image_description = (EditText) 
rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_user_description);

        //Loading image using universal image loader to imageView
        if (equipmentPicturesList.get(position) != null) {
            Constant.imageLoader.displayImage("file:///" + 
equipmentPicturesList.get(position).toString(), imageView, Constant.options,
                    new SimpleImageLoadingListener());
        }
        else {
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
}
    catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.loadStackTrace(e);
    }

    return rowView;
```

Comment: please post some coding attempts so that we can focus on that.

Comment: Thanks xlembouras and Xaver Kapeller. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

The `EditText` messes with the focus of whatever layout it is in. That can be a little tricky by itself, but in a `ListView` it causes all sorts of problems. But there is a way around that, it will work if you put the `EditText` inside the footer or header of the `ListView` with `addHeaderView` or `addFooterView`. The reason that it works in the header or footer is that the header and footer views are not recycled by the `ListView`. Alternatively you can call `setHasTransientState()` on the `EditText` to prevent it from being recycled even as a normal view inside the `ListView`.

But beware that turning off the view recycling - especially if you do it for multiple views - can impact performance and scrolling speed of the `ListView`.

Comment: Thank for your feedback Xaver kapeller. I have listview with images and edit text in each row. Editext used to save image name. Is there any other way to stop recycling of edittext ? Please advice

Comment: There are other ways, but you shouldn't try to stop view recycling, view recycling etc is the whole purpose of a `ListView`. Instead think of something else you can do besides having `EditTexts` in your `ListView`. Generally `EditTexts` in `ListViews` aren't that common in Android anyway. Normally a dialog is used to input data after the user picked an item from the `ListView`.